# OpenTelemetry collector does not export Metric attributes to New Relic

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, newrelic, open-telemetry, otlp-grpc

I am attempting to export Metrics to an OpenTelemetry collector container from my Node.js app, which then exports it to New Relic.

I am making a simple request counter:

```
const exporter = new OTLPMetricExporter();


const meter = new MeterProvider({
    exporter,
    interval: 10 * 1000,
    resource: new Resource({
        [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]: 'otlp-service',
    }),
}).getMeter('my-meter-name');

const requestCount = meter.createCounter('api.requests', {
    description: 'Count all incoming requests to API.',
});

...

onResponseFinished(res, () => {
        const statusCode = res.statusCode ? res.statusCode : 'N/A';
        const labels = { statusCode };
        requestCount.add(1, labels);
};
```

I want to use the status code attribute to be able to facet/group by different status codes in New Relic. For this, I need to export the status code attribute (label) alongside each request so I can use them in New Relic. However, these labels do not get exported in OTLP and are neither displayed in the logging exporter.
I have read about the `resource_to_telemetry_conversion: enabled: true` setting on [the OpenTelemetry GitHub page on export helpers](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/tree/main/exporter/exporterhelper) and [used in conjunction with Prometheus in this StackOverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71127150/how-can-find-or-correctly-export-resource-labels-of-opentelemetry-metrics-in-pro), however, adding this attribute to my OTLP exporter configuration causes it to shut down due to an invalid configuration file; it seems it was only meant to be used with Prometheus and not generally with OTLP.

This is my `otel-config.yml`:

```
extensions:
  health_check: {}
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
processors:
  batch: # compresses data and reduces number of outgoing connections.
exporters:
  logging:
    logLevel: debug
  otlp:
    endpoint: https://otlp.nr-data.net:4317
    headers:
      api-key: $NEW_RELIC_API_KEY
service:
  extensions: [health_check]
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging, otlp]
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging, otlp]
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging, otlp]
```

I am using WSL2 and:

```
➜  ~ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c
➜  ~ node --version
v14.18.1
```

`package.json` excerpt:

```
...
        "@opentelemetry/api": "^1.0.4",
        "@opentelemetry/exporter-metrics-otlp-grpc": "^0.27.0",
        "@opentelemetry/resources": "^1.0.1",
        "@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics-base": "^0.27.0",
        "@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions": "^1.0.1",
...
```

My question is: What settings need to be changed to export Metric attributes via OTLP, and for them to appear in New Relic?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found out this is caused by a version mismatch, as the [`opentelemetry-js` library](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js) JS OTLP exporters are still using an outdated version of [protobufs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers). The problem is being tracked under [this issue](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/issues/2886).